# Current website design template

Tags: website-design, website-templates

Is there a "template" so to say that is being used in most websites in 2020? 
As in what's the new design idea, designers are using?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Most people are going for Dark theme, I myself use a Dark Theme Through out my website.

some common design out there from my research.

1. full Hero sections - designers are going for full hero sections with full-screen cover view.

2.floating elements - pictures and text and are now being mixed and interlaced with each other.

3. Gif's and large bold hanging text - we are seeing more of Large text being used alone without pictures or buttons. just text and some geometric shapes.
4. Smaller footers - beginning to see designers lose the whole big footer with lots of junk information
5. Call to Action - an oldie but a goodie.

In My experience, the secret to designing a good page is 3 things:

a. Big full Hero section
b. Call To Action
c. A good footer

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This is totally biased, it's litteraly one person's opinion. I don't think _most people_ are going for dark theme or floating elements.

Comment: like i said.. its from my own research... my personal opinion and its a idea not a law...

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Might be better if you were to remove that link to 99designs. It looks suspiciously like spam, and I suspect it's the main reason you are are getting so many down votes, not because of your opinions. Graphic design contest sites are unethical because they exploit people. Read [No Spec!](https://www.nospec.com/). Thanks.